# How to use line break to debug Web App in Visual Studio that uses environment variable

Tags: asp.net, docker, environment-variables, containers, visual-studio-2019

I have ASP.Net web form application created using Visual Studio IDE. The app has code that uses environment variable like this:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("key")
```

The reason to use environment variable is for deploying in staging and production environment as a containerised app. But how do I run Visual Studio debug mode locally to use line break? Or how do I add environment variable in debug mode?

Preferably the environment variable is specific to the application locally.

There is no environment variable being set, so the code failed
'Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("key")"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the launchSettings.json feature to setup local environment variables for debug purposes. Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#lsj) to the documentation. Hope this helps.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using .Net full framework in Visual Studio Community 2019, the application is .Net 4.8. But the launchSettings.json feature seems like is for .Net Core. Is there another workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Web.Config Transformation can generate different web.config files under different publishing environments, which is very convenient and practical.

There is a default web.config in the newly created web project, and the format can also be defined as web.[name].config file. The rules defined in this configuration file will modify the web.config file when publishing.

In the default project, Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config files will be created, corresponding to the Debug and Release environments respectively.

[image]

1. First add the Test configuration

[image]

[image]

[image]
2.  Add Test config Transformation file
On web.confg, right click, Add Config Transform, VS will add Transformation file Web.Test.config for the newly created Test configuration

[image]
3.  Modify the Web.Test.config file.
This code needs to be uncommented.

[image]

4. Find the current project.

[image]
5.  Open it with Notepad and scroll to the bottom:
Just add this paragraph.

[image]

6. If Visual Studio pops up a prompt box, click Overwrite, and then save.

Comment: So your suggestion is not using environment variable, but generate different web.config for different environments? And the web.release.config file for production should not be added into the Repository, so the secrets are not exposed, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, this helps to avoid unknown errors caused by frequent switching of environment variables.